# Problem adressing ViewById in Kotlin - android:id not equals view:id ? (newbie question)

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin

I am pretty new to Kotlin and face the following challenge: I defined a TableLayout that merges multiple other TableLayouts in it. I think of them as a kind of squares for my UI and I want to make them simply clickable.

So I did the following to define a row of 3 TableViews in a TableRow in MultiSquare.xml:

```
  <TableRow
    android:padding="5dp">
    <include layout="@layout/basesquare" android:id="@+id/square01"/>
    <include layout="@layout/basesquare" android:id="@+id/square02"/>
    <include layout="@layout/basesquare" android:id="@+id/square03"/>
</TableRow>
```

And try to address them in my MultiSquareActivity as such:

```
 val mySquare01 : TableLayout = findViewById(R.id.square01)
    mySquare01.setOnClickListener {
        tvOutputMessage = findViewById(R.id.textView)
        tvOutputMessage.text = "Table" + mySquare01.id +  " was clicked!"
    }
```

However, I just receive the error message that R.id.square01 is null - and phew I don't really get the point why. Hope someone could help ^^

Question is: How to address square1 in ViewActivity?

Comment: do you `setContentView(R.layout.MultiSquare)` in `MultiSquareActivity`'s onCreate function?

Comment: yes I did - exactly the line of code before val  val mySquare01 : TableLayout  .... etc.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i figured it out myself - I had 2 problems with my approach:

1.) I had to get rid to the merge Tag in Square.xml, that I Merged into MultiSquare.xml

2.) I had to set an Id even for my child-Tables of the TableLayout in the included table, which sounds actually a little weird, but it works.

Square.xml:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:width="165dp">
  <TableRow>
     <include layout="@layout/basetable" android:id="@+id/basetable01"/>
     <include layout="@layout/basetable" android:id="@+id/basetable02"/>
     <include layout="@layout/basetable" android:id="@+id/basetable03"/>
  </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Multisquare.xml:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:stretchColumns="*"
android:width="1545dp"
android:padding="1.5dp">
  <TableRow android:padding="5dp">
     <include layout="@layout/basesquare" android:id="@+id/square01"/>
     <include layout="@layout/basesquare" android:id="@+id/square02"/>
     <include layout="@layout/basesquare" android:id="@+id/square03"/>
  </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

MultiSquareActivity:

```
    private lateinit var mySquare01 : TableLayout

    mySquare01 = findViewById(R.id.square01)
    val square01basetable01: TableLayout = mySquare01.findViewById(R.id.basetable01)
    
    square01basetable01.setOnClickListener {
       ...
    }
```